# Linux renaming files to add _00 after filename before extension

Tags: linux, centos, rename

What am I missing here, this seems so simple yet I cant get it to work.

I have a directory with files like AGPNDRAH01.jpg

I want a directory with files like AGPNDRAH01_00.jpg

```
rename 's/(\w+).jpg\$1\_00.jpg$//' *
```

Doesnt, work.  Centos linux.  Makes no sense to me why this isnt working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick hack that will do what you describe in bash:

```
cd /directory
for F in `ls -1 |awk -F. '{print $2}'`
do
  mv $F.jpg ${F}_00.jpg
done
```

For rename usage:

```
wmoore@bitbucket(/tmp/dowork)$ ls -1
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
wmoore@bitbucket(/tmp/dowork)$ rename .jpg _00.jpg *.jpg
wmoore@bitbucket(/tmp/dowork)$ ls -1
1_00.jpg
2_00.jpg
3_00.jpg
4_00.jpg
5_00.jpg
```

Comment: This worked, but i'm really curious why rename isnt working.

Comment: let's suppose the name of the picture has a "." in it before the .jpg :)

Comment: That did it you man page must be better equipped than mine.  rename .jpg _00.jpg *.jpg did it.  Thanks!

Comment: Then I'd suppose you'd be using a non-standard naming convention that my systems wouldn't employ, Marcel.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following bash script:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -print | while read FILE  
  do mv "${FILE}" "`dirname ${FILE}`/`basename ${FILE} .jpg`_00.jpg"
  done
```

That will find all .jpg files in or below the current directory and insert `_00` before `.jpg`.  If you only want it to handle the current directory start the find command with `find . -maxdepth 1`

Answer (score 1):

Double backslash at the end of the regex means **s**ubstitute **s/(\w+).jpg$1_00.jpg$** with an empty string.

I used this:

```
rename 's/\.jpg/_00.jpg/' *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with rename, but your regex doesn't look right.  It appears like you are trying to match files named like this **AGPNDRAH01.jpg.AGPNDRAH01_00.jpg** and change their name to nothing.

Are you sure you don't mean something like this instead?

```
rename 's/(\w+).jpg$/\$1\_00.jpg/' *
```

Comment: I tried a variant of that, and I tried what you have listed there.  Didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have a variant of redhat, and rename doesn't support the 's/' command. Here's a one-liner for you (You have to backslash parenthesis and plus-signs to get the functionality in sed):

```
for fl in *.jpg; do mv $fl `echo $fl | sed 's/\(\w\+\).jpg/\1_00.jpg/'`; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had a slash in the wrong place and an unnecessary backslash.

```
rename 's/(\w+).jpg/$1\_00.jpg/' *
```